# Python 3 : Why would you use urlparse/urlsplit

Tags: python-3.4, urlparse

I'm not exactly sure what these modules are used for.  I get that they split the respective url into its components, but why would that be useful, or what is an example of when to use urlparse?

Comment: This question seems too broad to me.

Comment: Why would it be useful to split a url into its components?

Comment: It will depend on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Well then what is the most common use of urlparse?

Comment: Eh. Closing as too broad. It's only slightly more focused than "What would you use string concatenation for?".

Comment: For getting query parameters , hostname etc. Yes @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it seems too broad. OP needs to read some tutorial and learn instead of posting question here

Comment: Why would you NOT want to split a URL into it's components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `urlparse` only if you need parameter. I have explained below why do you need parameter for.

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlsplit)

> urllib.parse.**urlsplit**(urlstring, scheme='', allow_fragments=True)
>
> This is similar to urlparse(), but does not split the params from the
> URL. This should generally be used instead of urlparse() **if the more
> recent URL syntax allowing parameters to be applied to each segment of
> the path portion of the URL (see [RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396.html)) is wanted**.

Hostname is always useful to store in variable to use it later or adding parameter, query to hostname to get the web page you want while scraping.

Regarding Parameter:

**FYI: According to RFC2396, parameter in url**

> Extensive testing of current client applications demonstrated that the
> majority of deployed systems do not use the ";" character to indicate
> trailing parameter information, and that the presence of a semicolon
> in a path segment does not affect the relative parsing of that
> segment. Therefore, parameters have been removed as a separate
> component and may now appear in any path segment. Their influence has
> been removed from the algorithm for resolving a relative URI
> reference.

Parameter are useful in scraping,
e.g. if the url is `http://www.example.com/products/women?color=green`

When you use `urlparse`, you will get parameter. Now You have to change it to `men` so it will be `http://www.example.com/products/men?color=green` and `kids`, `girl`, `boy` so on.

Comment: I read over the documentation, but why would getting the host name or the params of the url be useful?  What are you going to use these for?

Comment: After parsing the url how would you go about switching the parameters to create a new url?

Comment: url = ''http://www.example.com/products/'' param = 'men' url + param

Comment: @AranFreel I would suggest you to try it if you find difficulty after so many try, ask fresh question in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77267/discussion-between-vaibhav-mule-and-aran-freel).