# I want to get only URL from href statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get URL only from an 
i have tried a thing, But it works with Simple files When i place code into my actual wordpress page, It givess error..

```
<?php
$string = "this is my friend's website <a href=http://facebook.com/baberzaman > I think it is coll</a>";
$url = explode(' ',strstr($string,'http://'))[0];
?>
<br><br>
<?php echo $url; 
?>
```

It works good. but when i put it in wordpress. It give some '[' error in this line..

```
$url = explode(' ',strstr($string,'http://'))[0];
    ?>
```

I hope to get help soon

Thanks..

Comment: what is the version of php

Comment: I find it amusing that this and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30091297/python-3-why-would-you-use-urlparse-urlsplit has come up around the same time. Cause this guy could really do with a php version of this module :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Array dereferencing is not possible in your current version of php

your php version should be above 5.4. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742764/php-syntax-for-dereferencing-function-result) for detail explanation

For more info check out [this](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.0).

so you can use like this ,if you dont want to update to latest version

```
$url = explode(' ',strstr($string,'http://'));
echo $url[0];
```

and if your string does not have http:// then you can use this regex to extract value of href.

```
$pattern = '~\bhref\s*+=\s*+["\']?+\K(?!#)[^\s"\'>]++~';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $out);
echo $out[0];
```

Comment: Your this code worked. but one issue in this.. The String with URL came ( <a href="http://progsofts.com/remilamande/photo/good-picture/">Good Thing</a>) And it gave me out put (http://progsofts.com/remilamande/photo/good-picture/">Good) But i want Out put only link. (http://progsofts.com/remilamande/photo/good-picture/). this is extra ">Good Now please help me to solve this.. @PeterSmith

Comment: @peter   Your this code worked. but one issue in this.. The String with URL came ( <a href="progsofts.com/remilamande/photo/good-picture/">Good Thing</a>) And it gave me out put (progsofts.com/remilamande/photo/good-picture/">Good) But i want Out put only link. (progsofts.com/remilamande/photo/good-picture). this is extra ">Good Now please help me to solve this..

Answer (score 0):

```
function()[index]
```

is only available since php5 so. check out your php-version.
you could stilldo

```
$urlarray = explode(' ',strstr($string,'http://'));
$url = $urlarray[0];
```